# How is any algorithm expressed respectively by a grammar, a Turing machine and last but not least a rule-based system?

Tags: logic, algorithms, computer-science, turing-machines, formal-grammar

In [Herre & Schroeder-Heister's "Formal Languages and Systems"](http://www.cas.mcmaster.ca/%7Esancheg/EE_UCU2006_thesis/biblio/Formal%20Languages%20and%20Systems%20(RoutledgeFLS1995).pdf), on p7,

> Like **grammars**, **rule-based systems** (e.g. deductive systems in logic) are as powerful as **Turing
> machines**, i.e. they can be used to express any algorithm.

By "express any algorithm",
does it mean that an algorithm is expressed as a string in a language?

How is any algorithm expressed by any of the three?

- For a grammar, does it mean that a grammar generates a language?
- For a Turing machine, does it mean that a Turing machine accepts a language?
- How is a rule-based system used to express an algorithm?

Does their equivalence for "express any algorithm" mean the same as equivalence for computability in [Church-Turing thesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis):

> Church[3] and Turing[4][6] proved that these three formally defined classes of computable functions coincide: a function is **λ-computable** if and only if it is **Turing computable**, and if and only if it is **general recursive**.

- Does a rule-based system correspond to lambda calculus?
- What does a grammar correspond to?

Thanks.